# Class::new and Class#new same thing?

Tags: ruby

The class `Class` has a class method version of `new` and an instance method version of `new`. But because `Class` is an instance of `Class` doesn't that make the class method version of `new` the instance method version of `new`?

When i see the following

```rb
>> Class.new
=> #<Class:0x00007fca601fe898>
```

I think the `Class` object is an instance of `Class` so `new` is an instance method of the class `Class`. Rather then `new` is a class method of the class `Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class::new` and `Class#new` are the same.

In the sense that they actually refer to the same method. Their behavior however is very different because that method in turn calls other methods. (explained below)

Just like the `new` methods in other classes (`String.new`, `Array.new` etc.), `Class.new` resolves to `Class#new`. Ruby classes usually don't provide their own `new` class method. We can easily confirm this by replacing `Class#new`:

```
String.new #=> ""
Array.new  #=> []
Class.new  #=> #<Class:0x00007fef2517f5e0>

class Class
  def new(*args)
    "it's me, Class#new"
  end
end

String.new #=> "it's me, Class#new"
Array.new  #=> "it's me, Class#new"
Class.new  #=> "it's me, Class#new"
```

The original implementation of `Class#new` creates a new object by calling the receiver's `allocate` method and invoking that object's `initialize` method (passing arguments), something like:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

So `Class#new` is a simple [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) – the actual work is done by `allocate` and `initialize`. And that's where the difference comes from. By inspecting `initialize` we see that its owner is `Class` for `Class#initialize` but `BasicObject` for their instances:

```
Class.instance_method(:initialize).owner
#=> Class

Class.new.instance_method(:initialize).owner
#=> BasicObject
```

The confusion stems from the documentation which shows `#initialize` as `::new` (which is convenient because we usually call `new` and rarely, if ever, invoke `initialize` directly). So if you open the docs for [`Class::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-c-new) and click *"toogle source"* you're looking at the implementation for `Class#initialize` (or `rb_class_initialize` as it's called in C)

The only class I know that actually overrides the `new` class method is `Struct`, i.e. [`Struct::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Struct.html#method-c-new):

```
Struct.method(:new).owner        #=> #<Class:Struct>
Struct.method(:new).super_method #=> #<Method: Class#new>
```

Answer (score 5):

[Class::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-c-new) and [Class#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-i-new) are not the same.

> `Class::new` Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given
>   superclass.
>   `Class.new` Calls allocate to create a new object of
>   class's class, then invokes that object's initialize method, passing
>   it args.

If you click toggle source on the docs links above you can see just that.

Basically `Class.new` is the default initializer every other class in ruby inherits.
`Class::new` creates a new anonymous class.